# why I can inject JNDI string resource from WAR and not from EJB jar module?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, resources, cdi, websphere-8

I have an external String resource declared into server (either Jboss 7.1.1 or WAS 8) 
JBoss :

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1">
  <bindings>
     <simple name="jboss/resources/foovalue" value="helloworld"/>
  </bindings>
</subsystem>
...
```

I can get it nicely from my war module like this :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Footest
...
@Resource(name = "foovalue")
private String externalFoo;
...
```

but if I try to get it from an EJB module (Maven dependency as EJB type)  like

```
@Stateless
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooServiceLocal
...
    @Resource(name = "foovalue")
    private String externalFoo;
...
```

I got a null value !

did I missed something ?

Comment: Do you happen to have a relevant `resource-env-ref` in your `web.xml` and not in the `ejb-jar.xml`?

Comment: my bad.. I missed the ejb-jar.xml resource-ref entry ! work fine now ^^ thank you Nikos !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikos pointed me to the right solution : must have a **ejb-jar.xml** into classpath (src\main\resources\META-INF)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

        <enterprise-beans>
            <session>
                <ejb-name>FooServiceImpl </ejb-name>
                <resource-ref>
                    <res-ref-name>foovalue</res-ref-name>
                    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
                </resource-ref>
            </session>
        </enterprise-beans>
    </ejb-jar>
```

Note that if you use WAS 8.x you must declare the resource into a **ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml** file :

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <session name="FooServiceImpl" >
        <resource-ref name="foovalue" binding-name="foovalue"/>
    </session>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

The reference foo-value is declared into WAS 8 like :

Open administrative console, go into Environment > Manage Name Space Bindings. Select scope and

- Binding type = String
- Binding identifier = foovalue
- Name in name space= foovalue
- String value = helloworld